# How to make sense of this scala stacktrace?

Tags: scala

The following line results in an error in scala, I know that I am missing a argument in the split method. ≈

```
scala> "i am learning scala".split()
```

But I am not able to make sense of the stack trace generated due to this error.

```
<console>:25: error: overloaded method value split with alternatives:
  (x$1: String)Array[String] <and>
  (x$1: String,x$2: Int)Array[String]
 cannot be applied to ()
       "i am learning scala".split()
```

Can someone explain the above stack trace to me and how I can relate it to a missing argument?

Comment: It shows you two versions of `split`, one that takes a single parameter, one that takes two parameters. There is no version without any parameters.

Comment: The error message would be a bit clearer if there was just a single version of the method, then it tells you about the parameter mismatch (which it does not do now, because it does not know which one you intended to call)

Comment: That's not a stack trace, but a compilation error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole error message decomposes as such :

"Subject" :

```
overloaded method value split with alternatives:
  (x$1: String)Array[String] <and>
  (x$1: String,x$2: Int)Array[String]
```

"Verb" :

```
cannot be applied to ()
```

"Object":

```
 "i am learning scala".split()
```

So the whole first part is the subject, aka a description of what is concerned by the error. This subject is indeed the `overloaded method value split` followed by a reminder of the different valid signatures for this mehod. Don't search for what you did wrong here, it's only a description of the object concerned by the error ! (a quite verbose one, but still).

The verb gives you the problem, it "cannot be applied".

The object gives you the why : you called it with no arguments, and this doesn't match any of the valid signatures which you were reminded of in the "Subject" part.

Answer (score 0):

split method always need a delimiter, regex etc. as parameter. 
ex:

```
"i am learning scala".split(" ")
```

this will split the above string on SPACE " "
output:

```
Array[String] = Array("i","am","learning","scala")
```

And about the stacktrace, compiler is telling you to pass parameters to split method.